# How to access sails session in angular controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js

Hi I am trying to access sails session variable like

```
req.session.user = {
        id  : user.id,
        firstname : user.first_name,
        lastname  : user.last_name,
        auth_token : user.auth_token,
        email : user.email
      }
```

in my angular controller file but unable to access I tried

```
sails.config.sessions.user.name
```

but it's giving me error however I am able to access this in view as
<%=req.session.user.name%> and what are the best practice to handle session and authentication of app in sailsjs

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a conceptual error you have with how Angular and Sails work.

When you do something such as `<%=req.session.user.name%>` in Sails, that code is ran server side, rendered, and sent as a html file to the client.

What you are trying to do is access the `req` object on the client (angular is clientside code), but `req` only exists on your Sails server code.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I know that but can't we use sails variable in view's JS like in php we can use var a = '<?php $s; ?>';.So similar in sails if we have something

Comment: No, you can't. Your Sail's app will send your Angular javascript files to the client; once they are on the client (the browser), they will have no reference to the session.